# Tiling large single GeoTIFF raster into smaller GeoTIFF tiles?

Tags: raster, gdal, software-recommendations, open-source-gis, tiling

I have traditionally used proprietary software tools for tiling raster datasets but I am keen to explore the open source solutions as well.

Are there any open source solutions that can easily tile a GeoTIFF into smaller GeoTIFF (not png or jpg tiles) where you can set the dimensions yourself?

From what I have seen in QGIS, GDAL this is not as flexible as I hoped whilst Saga shows some promise.

Comment: Check this out: https://howtoinqgis.wordpress.com/2016/12/17/how-to-split-a-raster-in-several-tiles-using-qgis-or-python-gdal/

Comment: Thanks for the comments! Aaron your solution is what I was looking for.  Still not quite as functional as COTS Software but it does the job better than I had found myself!   Thanks for your comment Ed its a slightly different issue to the one you refer to.

Comment: I use Global Mapper to do this and you can break up the tiling in many ways and set custom file names.  You can also export to GMG - Global Mapper GRID as standard XYZ or TMS 256x256 or 512x512 tiles and then batch convert the GMG into geotiff.  So if you wanted to use GeoPackage Elevation Extension you can simply package up your folder of tiles into a GeoPackage and take that data on your mobile device.

Comment: Yeah Global Mapper is usually my go to and it is super cheap but I was trying to find a completely open source solution that could be used.  The QGIS vrt tiling does work pretty well but still not as good as GM

Comment: GRASS GIS can do that easily: https://grass.osgeo.org/grass74/manuals/r.tile.html - for a Python script style approach you can then use grass-session (see e.g. https://neteler.gitlab.io/grass-gis-analysis/05_grass_gis_python_session/)